# How to reference interface property

Tags: c#, interface, properties

I define an interface and build a class inherit it.

```
interface IOperator
{
    int Priority{ get; }
    string Identifier { get; }
    int Dimension { get; }

    Expression GetExpression(IVariable[] variables);
    object Excute(IVariable[] variables);

}

public class Op_Muti:IOperator
{
    int IOperator.Priority { get { return 40; } }
    string IOperator.Identifier { get { return "*"; } }
    int IOperator.Dimension { get { return 2; } }


public object IOperator.Excute(IVariable[] variables)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("{0} can't apply to {1}", Identifier, variables[0].VarType.ToString()));
}
```

}

The **Identifier** is defined in interface

```
string Identifier { get; }
```

and implement in class Op_Muti

```
string IOperator.Identifier { get { return "*"; } }
```

but can't reference in

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("{0} can't apply to {1}", Identifier, variables[0].VarType.ToString()));
```

Why?

Comment: @rawling incorrect duplicate.   OP has no problem with the other 4 members and there is only 1 inheritance

Comment: In your `Execute` method you probably need to use `IOperator.Identifier` instead not just refer to it as `Identifier`

Comment: Why are you using _explicit_ notation anyway? For a single interface?

Comment: @MickyD Disagree. OP has implemented 3 interface properties explicitly, is trying to implement the method explicitly, and is wondering why he can't access one of the explicitly-implemented interface properties. Sounds like OP needs to understand how implicit and explicit implementation of interface properties works? (... which is exactly what you've put in your followup comments...)

Comment: @Rawling the point I'm making is that whilst the answers explain well the concept of how to define and invoke a class with explicit members, none point out that _in order for a class member to invoke/refer-to an explicity-defined member, that `it must use the interface prefix too`_.  From within the class.  That's unexpected.  That was something I didn't know until I looked at this question.  _So I learnt something new today_

Comment: explicit interface implementations is something I would recommend against, unless there's a good reason for it.